# Deserialize key value string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, query-string, deserialization

I am using paypal NVP and NVP respond in key value pair string

Example

> TOKEN=EC-3XXXXXXXXXXX154J&BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS=1&CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionNotInitiated&TIMESTAMP=2012-07-10T11:45:59Z&CORRELATIONID=ecf9bfe9b1168&ACK=Success&VERSION=64.0&BUILD=3242673&EMAIL=govind_1341920205_per@gmail.com&PAYERID=3V85HKW32SXKG&PAYERSTATUS=verified&FIRSTNAME=Govind&LASTNAME=Malviya&COUNTRYCODE=US&SHIPTONAME=Govind
>   Malviya&SHIPTOSTREET=1 Main St&SHIPTOCITY=San
>   Jose&SHIPTOSTATE=CA&SHIPTOZIP=95131&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US&SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME=United
>   States&ADDRESSSTATUS=Confirmed&CURRENCYCODE=USD&AMT=30.90&SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&HANDLINGAMT=0.00&TAXAMT=0.00&DESC=test EC
>   payment&INSURANCEAMT=0.00&SHIPDISCAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=30.90&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test
>   EC
>   payment&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=false&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=Govind
>   Malviya&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=1 Main
>   St&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=San
>   Jose&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=CA&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=95131&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME=United
>   States&PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE=0

I want to desrialize it in strongly typed data, like JavaScriptSerializer do for json string. Please don't provide solution using dictionary i want to avoid magic string, I can add attribute on each property.

My class is

```
 public class GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse : IPaypalResponse
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public string BillingAgreementAcceptedStatus { get; set; }
        public string CheckoutStatus { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string CorrelationID { get; set; }
        public Status Acknowledgement { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Build { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PayerID { get; set; }
        public string PayerStatus { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string ShiptoName { get; set; }
        public string ShiptoStreet { get; set; }
        public string ShipToCity { get; set; }
        public string ShipToState { get; set; }
        public string ShipToZip { get; set; }
        public string ShipToCountryCode { get; set; }
        public string ShipToCountryName { get; set; }
        public string AddressStatus { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAmount { get; set; }
        public string HandlingAmount { get; set; }
        public string TaxAmount { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string InsuranceAmount { get; set; }
        public string ShipdiscAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestCurrencycode { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShippingAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestHandlingAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestTaxAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestDescription { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestInsuranceAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipdiscAmount { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestInsuranceOptionOffered { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToName { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToStreet { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToCity { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToState { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToZip { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToCountryCode { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestShipToCountryName { get; set; }
        public string PaymentRequestInfoErrorCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what do you thing about using reflection? I doubt that there is a ready-to-use serializer to do what you want.

Comment: Reflections and attributes sounds good to me

Comment: @Codesleuth I guess there are could be a lot of different responses, but reflecting _single_ fixed class seems overkill for me too.

Comment: If I were you I would remove some of the code you have put in your question, it looks like sensitive data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to convert your string to `NameValueCollection`. The rest is just `reflection`

```
string responseString = "TOKEN=EC......";
var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);
GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse respObj = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse();
foreach (var p in respObj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    p.SetValue(respObj, dict[p.Name]);
}

//respObj is ready to use
```

Comment: The only thing I would say about this is you are adding a dependancy on `System.Web` just for a small parsing function, seems a bit OTT for me (unless the OP already uses `System.Web`).

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ to extract your data into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which you could then use to map the data in your class e.g.

```
var paypalResponse = "...";
var data = paypalResponse.Split('&') 
                         .Select(x => x.Split('=')) 
                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

You could then pass this into the constructor of your `GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse` class or even do this inside it e.g.

```
public class GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse : IPaypalResponse
{
    public GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponse(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        this.Token = data["TOKEN"];
        this.BillingAgreementAcceptedStatus = data["BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS"];
        ...
    }
}
```

Using reflection for something like this might be more hassle than it's worth as your properties don't match exactly so you would need to add metadata attributes to each of your properties.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya Looking at your answer, you used the solution provided you with but swapped out the mapping part. So *we* solved your problem. You should always mark the answer that provided you the most help (even if it isn't the complete solution).

Comment: I didn't accept any answer yet, the how can you tell this? thanks for downvote.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya it's fine if you post your solution, but you shouldn't be posting it as a new answer that gives the impression you are going to accept that one - it goes against the whole point of the site.

Comment: so you mean don't post answer and accept half answer right? great!!

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya You have basically taken the solution I gave you and modified it to suit your needs (that's what SO is all about). However, you are supposed to update your answer to say "*this is the solution I ended up with*" and accept the answer which gave you the most help (regardless if it's only part of the overall solution). Otherwise, what is the point in anyone posting answers in the first place? It's not very good etiquette...

Answer (score 1):

So, since there is no ready-to-use deserializator for your issue, you should do the following:

1. Add attributes to each property which represent the paypal's response'.
2. Reflect the class instance' properties and cache them into the `Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>`, where the string is attribute's value.
3. Iterate through `"some string".Split(..)` method's result on paypal response, collect strings and values, and then store them into the corresponding property which you should look up in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, instead of reinventing the wheel; how about you use the PayPal SDK?

http://paypal.github.io/sdk/

The one you want is the [Express Checkout SDK for C#](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/)

It already has all the fields you need with the correct data type, and it has the added benefit of automating all the calling / parsing of the response behind a couple of simple function calls.

Hand-building your own API call and parsing the response is not the best approach to this. Sure, *eventually* you're going to get it to work, but until you do so, it's going to be a time consuming and error prone process...

Comment: Both the links are broken. Would you please update them?